# Alternative to KeyMesh addon?

Tags: animation, add-on, shape-keys

This weekend I tried keymesh and in the beginning, it was an amazing and fun learning process.
But, I have encountered so many glitches and bugs later on that it's simply not possible to further work with it on a professional level.

I heard that it was abandoned by the dev.

So, Is there an addon that has similar functions to keymesh?
I know shape keys work kind of the same. The problem I see with shape keys is that you can't create new vertices within the mesh.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A new addon called "Claymation" is coming for Blender 3.2+
**[This is the link](https://twitter.com/_pepeland_/status/1494594328844509203?s=20&t=qxqHygplG0KIccxQHDN5-A)** where the developers mention they are working in the upgrade from the previous "Keymesh" addon.

Answer (score 0):

There is also FZSwapper by Fruitzeus: https://fruitzeus.gumroad.com/l/swapper
It's not quite the same but treads similar ground.

Answer (score 0):

Keymesh too?

Complete rewrite of iconic Keymesh add-on by Pablo Dobarro, that lets you create stop-motion animations inside Blender.

https://nickberckley.gumroad.com/l/keymesh_too